# Are the effects of not using volatile keyword platform specific?

Tags: java, concurrency, volatile

Are the effects of not using volatile keyword platform specific?

On Ubuntu 13.04 x64 with openJDK 1.7 using or not using volatile keyword has no effect; in the sense that the program executes as expected when not using volatile.

I want to know what is the exact reason of this and why it doesn't fail every time like in Windows with Oracle's JVM.

I know what volatile guarantees and when it should be used. This is not the question.

example:

```
public class VolatileTest {
private static boolean test;
public static void main(String... args) {
    Thread a = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            test = true;

        }
    });

    Thread b = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(!test) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(test);
            }
        }
    });

    a.start();
    b.start();
}}
```

Comment: How did you test it and can prove it to us here?

Comment: example code?  Java itself, all of it should be platform independent.

Comment: Perhaps `volatile` hasn't been necessary in the first place :)

Comment: A particular small sample program "working" as expected does not mean that the same snippet of code embedded in a large application executing with a more complicated JVM state will also "Work"

Comment: The `volatile` keyword is not `absent` from Java. THis is not the question either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are the effects of not using volatile keyword platform specific?

The Java Memory Model describes how a program *must* behave when it is properly sychronized, but does not say much about how a program *could* behave when it is not (apart from the causality requirement for example). So in theory, it is platform specific.

In practice, it is platform and JVM specific. Typically, x86 architectures have fairly a strong memory model and removing the `volatile` keyword will often not break your program (i.e. the code still behaves as if the variable was still `volatile`).

Some (generally older) processors are even sequentially consistent, which means that your program will behave as if everything were synchronized.

On the other hand, on processors with weaker memory models such as ARM, it is easier to observe the effects of a broken multi-threaded program.

Similarly, some JVM are more aggressive in their optimisations and will reorder instructions, hoist variables etc. differently. With a given JVM, the parameters you use could have an effect too. For example on Hotspot, if you disable JIT compilation, you will probably "fix" some thread safety issues.

See also [this post on memory models](http://preshing.com/20120930/weak-vs-strong-memory-models).

Answer (score 3):

Volatile is not platform-specific in its effects. It complies to the specification set out in the [Java Memory Model.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Memory_Model) Its *implementation* in the JVM is obviously different for each platform, as for how it enforces memory barriers.

Can you provide sample code? Your test is probably misleading.

Comment: I have added a small example.

Comment: Also, isn't it a compiler optimization?! So, the JVM shouldn't matter.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that while `volatile`'s effects itself are not platform-specific, the effects of omitting `volatile` in a place where it is necessary *may* be platform specific.

Comment: @Rs7 It is not a compiler *optimization*. It has the specific effect of *forcing* consistent memory visibility. The fact that your code works on Ubuntu and not on Windows is the **canonical** example (pardon the pun) of why it is necessary -- different OSes may schedule threads differently, to different cores with separate caches, etc. etc. The `test` variable might **never** be made visible to the second thread without enforcing it with volatile. I suggest reading *Java Concurrency in Practice* for more information.

Comment: "Java Memory Model permits the compiler to reorder operations and cache values in registers" from _Java Concurrency in Practice_ . So, the JIT compiler makes the _optimization_ ... The question is, the JIT will compile the byte code the same way every time? So, on a specific JVM I can run this example for ever and obtain the same result?

Comment: That doesn't refer to the `volatile` keyword. That refers to the **absence** of memory barriers such as volatile.

Answer (score 1):

> A field may be declared volatile, in which case the Java Memory Model ensures
>   that all threads see a consistent value for the variable. -- JLS 8.3.1.4

Volatile guarantees consistent view of the variable. Native implementations of volatile prohibit the CPU/Core from keeping the variable in it's registers for the computations performed by the thread, so that all the threads running on other CPUs/Core can have consistent view of that variable.

You can not conclude that it's not working by running few test cases. These kind of issues may get caught in 1 out of thousands of test.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a field volatile ensures all threads see the current value of the field. Not declaring a field volatile does not ensure other threads won't see a modification on the field made by a thread.

Modifying a little your example:

```
public class VolatileTest {

private static boolean test = false;

public static void main(String... args) {
    Thread a = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            boolean localTest = test;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("changing local test");
            test = !localTest;

        }
    });

    Thread b = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            boolean localTest = test;
            while(!localTest) {
                localTest = test;
            }
        }
    });

    a.start();
    b.start();
}}
```

This one will read the field `test` a lot of times, then the JVM will cache `test` value for thread `b`. Making thread `b` sleep will make `test` field not be read so much, then the JVM won't try to "optimize" (caching the value of `test` on thread `b`) - but if `test` was declared volatile, the JVM would have no means to cache `test`'s value.

The test was run on Ubuntu Lucid 64 bits, with Oracle's Java 1.7.0.

Answer (score 0):

The example code you have provided does not exercise the loop enough to get JIT optimised. It will run in the interpreter, and as such your code will (most likely) not be subject to any compiler optimisation tricks that will cause it to fail. The CPU itself is also unlikely to pull tricks advanced enough to thwart this code, especially considering the relatively huge timescales involved here with those sleeps.

However, this is an implementation detail of your particular JVM. Your program is racy even if the bug will never manifest on your particular combination of hardware, JVM and operating system.

Answer (score 0):

- For performance optimisation, a compiler & JVM implementation may move code order and also use registers or caches visible to just one thread.  Obviously, this behaviour varies for each implementation.
- That means that an updated value for a variable may be visible to one one thread; while all other threads read a stale varlue
- If you want to safely accessing a variable from multiple threads, guaranteeing consistent reads of the most up-to-date value, you `must` use `volatile`.  This behaviour provided by volatile is not platform-specific.
- It is possible that you could fluke it under certain scenarios/implementations and see consistent up-to-date values without `volatile`, but that's pot luck & no way to program.